# using rxjava to filter list 1 using list 2 via id

Tags: kotlin, rx-java

I have a `Single<List<Person>>` emitting 50 item list and a `Singe<List<Winner>>` emitting 5 item list.  Winner and Person share an `id` field.  I want to use kotlin and rxjava to end up with a `Single<List<Person>>`.  So it emits a list of people who are winners.

I tried subscribing to getWinners() and did not receive any result.

```
fun getPersonObservable(): Observable<Person> = 
    api.getPersonListSingle().toObservable().flatMap { 
        Observable.fromIterable(it) }

fun getWinnerObservable(): Observable<Winner> =
    api.getWinnerListSingle().toObservable().flatMap {
        Observable.fromIterable(it) }

fun getWinners(): Single<List<Person>> =
    getPersonObservable().zipWith(getWinnerObservable())
    .filter { (person, winner) -> poerson.id == winner.id }
    .map { (person, winner) -> person }.toList()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter on all users with any from winners
`allUsers` and `winnerUsers` is a test data in real this would be your datasource from network layer.

```kotlin
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Single

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello World!")
    val allUsers: Single<List<AppUser>> = Single.create { emitter ->
        emitter.onSuccess(
            listOf(
                AppUser(1, "silentsudo"),
                AppUser(2, "stackoverflow")
            )
        )
    }

    val winnerUsers: Single<List<AppUser>> = Single.create { emitter ->
        emitter.onSuccess(
            listOf(
                AppUser(2, "stackoverflow"),
            )
        )
    }

    Single.zip(allUsers, winnerUsers,
        { user: List<AppUser>, winners: List<AppUser> ->
            UserWrapper(
                user,
                winners
            )
        })
        .subscribe { userWrapper ->
            userWrapper
                .user.filter { item -> userWrapper.winners.any { winner -> item.id == winner.id } }
                .map { winnerUsers ->
                    println(winnerUsers)
                }
        }
}

data class AppUser(val id: Int, val name: String)

data class UserWrapper(val user: List<AppUser>, val winners: List<AppUser>)
```

Comment: is there a way to do it more functionally and avoiding your nested callback?  I'm not sure if you cpould

Comment: which line you this is a callback?